# Nginx: реализация зеркальных серверов для балансирования нагрузки

Tags: linux, nginx, веб-сервер

Есть nginx-балансировщик с белым адресом для хостинг-сети.

Поступила задача для повышения отказоустойчивости сделать такой же зеркальный nginx-балансировщик, который будет лежать на другом кластере. Они будут синхронизироваться тем самым имея одинаковые конфигурации, и в случае, если "отваливается" один (из-за отказа кластера или какой-нибудь другой причины) второй бы подхватывал на лету и пользователи не заметили каких-либо перебоев в работе их виртуальных серверов.

Подскажите, где об этом можно почитать или как корректней это реализовать?

Comment: что-т странное хотите - два балансировщика с двумя белыми адресами, работающие как один? Придется сверху третий прикручивать, что б слить их в одно логически целое

Comment: Вариант, который мне видится рабочим — мониторинг работоспособности основного сервера и в случае его отказа переброс DNS на запасной. Даунтайм будет составлять не более TTL соответствующей A/AAAA записи.

Comment: Только имейте в виду, что у вас противоречие в постановке задачи: в заголовке балансировка, а в тексте отказоустойчивость.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов если есть возможность сделать два на одном белом ip-адресе, то было даже лучше, но так сделать, как я понимаю, маловероятно? А так, всё верно, требуется два балансера работающих как логическое одно целое.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev разве нельзя сделать балансирующие сервера на nginx'е зеркальными и тем самым повысить отказоустойчивость за счёт подхватывания одним балансером на лету всех запросов на себя в случае "падения" второго?

Comment: Именно для реализации хотелки потребуется некое звено выше двух кластеров. Клиент стучится в балансировщик-ТОП, а тот уже смотрит - какому балансировщику-1-2  отдать запрос. Единственный метод отвечать многим с одного белого IP - роутинг в том или ином виде.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов но если ложится топ, то тогда как будут идти запросы? Получается, что в случае падения топ-балансера перестаёт работать всё.

Comment: Ну, наконец-то дошло. Гуглите в сторону того, как организуется отказоустойчивость. Топ всегда контролирует ноды. Реализация либо программная - она уже стоит - балансировщик, либо аппаратная - запрос кидается на конкретную железку-маршрутизатор. 
Ваша задача изначально поставлена криво. Делать "такой же" - это делать вторую ноду. А вот кто ей рулить будет? 
Оптимальный вариант - перейдите на облачный хостинг и проблема с железом будет проблемой поставщика услуг.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev `Даунтайм будет составлять не более TTL соответствующей A/AAAA записи`, а также от хостеров, которые предоставляют DNS резолверы своим абонентам: прямоты их рук и их собственного понимания как надо кешировать запросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку перед балансировщиком нагрузки никакой другой балансировщик уже не поставить, проблему переключения трафика надо решать на каком-то другом уровне. К сожалению, ни один из доступных вариантов не даёт мгновенного переключения.

Самый простой вариант - это DNS. При падении балансировщика вы просто удаляете его IP из записи DNS, и через какое-то время про этот адрес все забудут. Длительность этого самого "какого-то времени" зависит от настроенного TTL, и по умолчанию равна суткам. Можно поставить по-меньше - но следите чтобы не пришлось делать балансировщик нагрузки уже для DNS-сервера. Ну и всегда есть вариант, что чей-то рекурсивный резолвер закеширует ответ от вашего сервера аж на трое суток.

---

Вариант по-сложнее - это зеркалирование IP. Суть в том, что при падении балансировщика вы его IP-адрес назначаете другому балансировщику, и все запросы сразу начинают идти на него (не забудьте только заранее создать два адреса, для служебного трафика и для публичного - иначе как вы будете его чинить?). Ну как "сразу"? Как только сетевое оборудование узнает куда слать пакеты, и тут есть четыре варианта.

Если оба балансировщика находятся в одной подсети - то балансировщик начнет принимать пакеты в тот момент, когда вы назначили ему адрес, тут все проблемы - только в своевременном обнаружении отказа. Тут помогут протоколы CARP или VRRP. Вообще-то эти протоколы придуманы для маршрутизаторов, но их можно применять и в других ситуациях.

Если оба балансировщика находятся в разных подсетях, но в одной организации - вам помогут протоколы динамической маршрутизации, например OSPF. Надо поднять на каждом OSPF-демон, и начать анонсировать маршрут к обоим IP-адресам с разным приоритетом, как будто вы маршрутизатор. При выключении балансировщика маршрутизаторы относительно быстро заметят изменение топологии сети и направят трафик другому балансировщику.

Если оба балансировщика находятся в одной организации, но организация чужая (облако) и вы там не можете настраивать OSPF - пишите в поддержу хостеру. У них обязано быть какое-то решение, проблема-то стандартная.

Если оба балансировщика находятся в разных облаках - вам нужно купить себе IP-адреса у регистратора, зарегистрировать свою автономную систему (AS) и заключить договор с хостером чтобы те анонсировали вашу AS и ваши адреса через BGP. Ну и согласовать прекращение анонса при выключении балансировщика. Ну или можно договориться с хостером чтобы те принимали ваши анонсы BGP. Тут время переключения будет порядка десятков минут (ну, если повезет). Этот метод быстрее чем DNS, но медленнее локальных вариантов. Возможно, лучше будет в каждом месте поставить по два балансировщика, чтобы иметь возможность быстро переключиться между ними - а BGP оставить на случай выключения всего дата-центра.

---

Ну и совет напоследок - какой бы вы вариант не выбрали, проверьте что он работает! Не надо пополнять список организаций, которые об этой проверке забыли :-)

Comment: _Суть в том, что при падении балансировщика вы его IP-адрес назначаете другому балансировщику, и все запросы сразу начинают идти на него_

Вы ввиду имеете какое-то автоматическое назначение/перекидывание IP-адреса или это делать вручную?

Comment: @ThePinkLord конечно же оно должно быть автоматическим

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать такое гуглить? Как сформулировать точнее запрос?

Comment: @ThePinkLord с аббревиатур, которые я привёл. DNS, CARP, VRRP, OSPF, BGP. Ещё есть термин High availability (HA)